# Blender issue after importing fspy file

Tags: fspy

UPDATE: Issue was solved by reinstalling the driver.

I have a problem with importing fspy file into Blender which never happen to me before. It looks like Blender crushed after importing the file....I have tried to update to the latest version Blender and reinstall the fspy plug in. But none of them solved the problem. I would be really appreciated if someone can help me with the issue :)

[image]

Comment: The fspy addon appears to have last been updated over two years ago so it's possible that it isn't compatible with the current Blender versions. It's an external addon, not part of Blender anyway so you'll need to contact the author if he's still around.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I reinstalled the driver and it works again!

Comment: Glad to hear it!